# What do these valgrind/GNU debugger error messages mean?

Tags: c++, debugging

My program terminates correctly and according to Valgrind, there is no leaked memory.

But the following message appears when the object method is run for the very first time.

```
Use of uninitialised value of size 8
```

Getting more detail on the above yeilds

```
==18787== Use of uninitialised value of size 8
==18787==    at 0x4017F3: Grid::init(int) (grid.cc:90)
==18787==    by 0x401D2A: main (main.cc:43)
==18787==  Uninitialised value was created by a stack allocation
==18787==    at 0x401BE4: main (main.cc:11)
```

I also see the following messages:

```
Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
Invalid free() / delete / delete[] / realloc()
Address 0x7ff000b08 is on thread 1's stack
```

Here is the code of Grid::init

```
void Grid::init(int n){
    if (!(&(this->theGrid))) { this->clearGrid(); } //If non-empty, destroys grid

    this->theGrid = new Cell*[n]; //Create new grid of size n x n
    this->td = new TextDisplay(n); //new Text Display 
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        this->theGrid[i] = new Cell[n];
        for(int j = 0; j < n; j++){ //Cell initializations
            (this->theGrid[i][j]).setDisplay(this->td); //set display
            (this->theGrid[i][j]).setCoords(i, j); //set co-ordinates
            (this->theGrid[i][j]).setState(0); //default state
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So, what's the code of `Grid::init` and which line is line 90?

Comment: …and which line is line 90?

Comment: Actually, anytime (this->theGrid) is called for the first time, I get the same uninitialized value of size 8 error.

Comment: What's with `if (!(&(this->theGrid)))`? You appear to be inspecting the address of a member variable - that's probably never going to be non-NULL (even if `this` is NULL - in which case you're already in dangerous territory due to calling a method on NULL - `theGrid` is going to be at some offset).

Comment: @Jay That should reveal your problem - see my updated answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing you have code that looks like:

Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s):

```
bool value /* nothing */;
if (value) {
}
```

Invalid free:

```
char* buf = new char[10000];
buf = &x;
delete [] buf;
```

Now that you posted code, I'm assuming line 90 is this one:

```
if (!(&(this->theGrid))) { this->clearGrid(); } //If non-empty, destroys grid
```

And the issue is that you aren't initializing `theGrid` to `nullptr` in your constructor, and then you end up maybe `delete[]`-ing a non-`new[]`-ed array. Also, that code would read way cleaner if you just did:

```
if (!theGrid) {
    clearGrid();
}
```

You don't need `this->` everywhere. And I don't understand why you're taking the address of `theGrid`.

Comment: Actually the constructor has "this->theGrid = NULL;". Does it make a difference to use nullptr instead? Also what does if(!theGrid) mean? Does it mean if theGrid is not null? Or does it mean if theGrid is null?

Comment: No it doesn't, and you really don't need `this->` everywhere. `!theGrid` checks for `theGrid` being non-null. But you really want to check specifically that `theGrid` is non-null, not the *address* of `theGrid` being non-zero. Those are not equivalent.